# Android app keeps crashing with something to do with id's

Tags: java, android, xml

I am currently trying to make a basic android app and trying to wrap my head around some crashes.

I've tried commenting out various parts of the code and compiling and running. As far as I can tell it seems to be when I have a Button and TextView both in a second activity. I am trying to make the app to transfer text put in by the user in the main activity to a second activity. (after a button is pushed). I am trying to get the second activity to have a button that returns to the first activity and also show the text that was put in from the main activity.

Here is the code for the main activity:

```
package com.example.brochura;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.lang.String;

public class Main extends Activity
{
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.brochura.MESSAGE";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view)
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Deployed.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the second activity:

```
package com.example.brochura;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Deployed extends Activity
{
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.brochura.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.return_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                finish();
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(Main.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        setContentView(R.layout.deployed);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        textView.setText(message);

    }
}
```

The crash happens when I try to go to the second activity (deployed)

Here is the xml for the Main and Deployed classes:

(main.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/deploy_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

(deployed.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/return_button"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="Return"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_text"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance and I am fairly new to mobile development so any pointers that anyone can give me would also be greatly appreciated.

--- UPDATE:
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.brochura"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"
    />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Deployed" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the logcat

```
I/ActivityManager( 1180): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.brochura/.Main} from pid 1552
I/ActivityManager( 1180): Start proc com.example.brochura for activity com.example.brochura/.Main: pid=2013 uid=10052 gids={50052}
I/ActivityManager( 1180): Displayed com.example.brochura/.Main: +321ms
E/AndroidRuntime( 2013): Process: com.example.brochura, PID: 2013
E/AndroidRuntime( 2013):    at com.example.brochura.Main.sendMessage(Main.java:36)
W/ActivityManager( 1180):   Force finishing activity com.example.brochura/.Main
W/ActivityManager( 1180): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b131c5f0 u0 com.example.brochura/.Main t7 f}
W/InputDispatcher( 1180): channel 'b149a920 com.example.brochura/com.example.brochura.Main (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher( 1180): channel 'b149a920 com.example.brochura/com.example.brochura.Main (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
I/ActivityManager( 1180): Process com.example.brochura (pid 2013) has died.
W/InputDispatcher( 1180): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'b149a920 com.example.brochura/com.example.brochura.Main (server)'
I/WindowState( 1180): WIN DEATH: Window{b149a920 u0 com.example.brochura/com.example.brochura.Main}
```

Comment: Please post the [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
put this line in first actvity.

Intent i=new Intent(First.this,second.class);
                i.putExtra("strin", "HI this is my text");
                startActivity(i);







and put this line in second activity 

Intent i=getIntent();
    String str=i.getStringExtra("strin");


declare both activity in manifest
```

Comment: This did work but I must confess I have no clue why. If you or anyone could explain what was going and why this worked I would love to know.

Comment: you was trying to send string value to second activity but you also declare that value in second  activity also so always put your variable name in i.putExtra("strin", "HI this is my text");   unique and get with same name it will always work